# Analyze the continuity of a real-valued function of two variables.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

> Consider the function

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}|y/x^2|\cdot 2^{-|y/x^2|}, & x\neq 0\\ 0, & else\end{cases}$$

> Show that $f$ isn't continuous at 
>   (0,0) while the restriction $f|_G$ on each line $G$ through the origin is continuous on $G$.

**Solution:**

So my idea was to just show that $f$ isn't continuous without restricting it at all. So by using polar coordinates, we get:

$\lim_{r\to 0} |\frac{1}{r}\frac{sin(\varphi)}{\cos(\varphi)^2}|2^{-|\frac{1}{r}\frac{sin(\varphi)}{\cos(\varphi)^2}|}=0$

since

$\lim_{k \to 0} \frac{k}{2^k}=0$

so $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.... so somehow what I just did isn't correct or isn't what I intended to. :/

Where's my mistake?

Comment: In the exponential of number 2, there is "7", is it correct?

Comment: Have you tried just approaching along a non-linear function, in particular $y = x^2$? Then the absolute value terms go to 1 in the limit, and you're left a nonzero limit as $x$ tends to 0. (I'm in a multivariable class currently and we never ventured anywhere near change of coordinates for these questions.)

Comment: No, why should I? I just see a function that always tends to zero. I just can't see how the second term shouldn't dominate the first. I mean, we have basically $f(x,y)$ vs $ 2^{f(x,y)}$. The second grows like crazy, the later not that much.